# Can't scroll inside ScrollView, when there are TextInputs

Tags: react-native

I have ScrollView inside that ScrollView, I have TextInputs, the scroll doesn't work in the area of TextInput. How to fix that?

```
render () {
return (
<View>
    <ScrollView
    ref='keyboardScroll'
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}
    >
    <View> 
    <TextInput 
    placeholder='First Name'
    />
    </View>
    <View> 
    <TextInput 
    placeholder='Last Name'
    />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
</View>
)}
```

Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/VkhMlISEX8o) with the issue.

Comment: Try wrapping your StyleView with a `<View style={{flex: 1}}>`

Comment: @Atef I just have added style={{flex: 1} both to View and ScrollView, however, it still works buggy.  For example, if I'm in 4th TextInput, it doesn't scroll, However, if I first scroll outside TextInput, then inside TextInput it will work.

Comment: Try adding `flex: 1` to your ScrollView in the `contentContainerStyle` object.

You will have this code: `<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex :1}} ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of that problem. The main problem was that text font size was too big for the TextInput field, which causes scroll inside the TextInput, so there are 2 solutions: 1) decrease font size 2) make the height of the TextInput field bigger. Also this solution solved another problem: [Placeholders in TextInput are moving during the scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642639/placeholders-in-textinput-are-moving-during-the-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Android, where the placeholder was scrolling just a little bit up and down and preventing the `ScrollView` from scrolling. I managed to fix it by adding the following styles on the `TextInput`:

```
paddingTop: 0,
paddingBottom: 0,
paddingLeft: <whatever>,
paddingRight: <whatever>
```